# Can I use different API's from various services in the same app?

Tags: api

I've already developed an application using the YouTube API. Now I just need to do some functions with the Instagram API in the same app. Can I add the Instagram API in that app and use both? is that valid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This is very common in Android apps. It is up to you to ensure that you handle logging in to the APIs correctly and that you don't violate any terms of service for accessing the services, but just using the APIs will not cause a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid and very common in practice. Usually you may need to use different services in your app from different servers such as your custom server , Google ,Facebook etc.
So you will be having different interface services written for performing such operations. For example using retrofit  with different APIs interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many APIs as you want just don't overload your app with API you will never need.

Consider you want your users to be able to login with Facebook or Google (thing that you may have already seen in many apps).

And in addition you want your users to be able to pay with different payment methods (PayPal, VISA, Mastercard, PayTM)...

The only limit is the number of services you want your app to have.

Note: By default the Android framework itself has a set of APIs.